# Porting openTTD to iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a big fan of openTTD. I would like to play it on my iOS device but due to GPL problems with the app store, there is no openttd app available to download. But I found this cool repo, where somebody did a coding for iPad: https://github.com/zodttd/OpenTTD 
I followed the install instructions https://github.com/zodttd/OpenTTD/blob/master/INSTALL.txt but I was unable to compile the code.

I am new to Xcode, but I figured out signing my app, choosing my phone for a build target, but always I was ending with this message:

[image]

It looks like that programmer hasnt changed <> to "" in include, but I don`t think so that's the real problem. I think it is more a problem in the Xcode settings.

So when some of Xcode experts have a little bit time for playing, just please try to download this repo and run it. If you are successful please write more concrete steps how can I run it and what are important settings in Xcode. I will be cool for whole openTTD community if they can play openTTD on their iOS devices ;-)

Big thanks.

Comment: Could be due to multiple reason and since the repo is 8 years old has not updated, there is a huge chance it may have to be ported again !

Comment: I know, but this errors which I received weren't because the code is 8 years old.